# UIBezierPath to become progressively thicker and then thinner

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uibezierpath

I'm having an `UIBezierPath` that is created when I swipe around the screen. But I want to make **the line progressively thicker and then thin** again. The result should somehow look like in Fruit Ninja as shown in the picture below

[image: Fruit Ninja Swipe]

Is there a special method for `UIBezierPath` or has somebody more experience with path-transformation?

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-advanced-freehand-drawing-techniques--mobile-15602